# Keep Text Edit mode when setting another form as active

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi

I'm working on a little Clipboard helper using WinForms. When user copies an item, it gets saved into my internal clipboard. Then when user presses and holds Ctrl+v my form displays, showing the recent clipboard items and user can use up/down arrows to change the clipboard. This means that you can quickly paste historical clipboard items. It's mostly working but I have a problem which I can't find a 'nice' way around.

When editing text, say renaming a folder in Windows Explorer, user presses ctrl+v, my form comes to the front which steals the focus and exits text edit mode in Windows Explorer. I could use SetWindowPos() from the WinApi so that my form does not steal focus... The problem is I *need* focus so that I can capture the up/down keys. I do have a keyboard hook so I can actually capture the key presses but then when I select next item, that gains focus and there are quite a few ugly scenarios I'd have to capture.

So, is there a way to set my whole app to never gain focus or can anyone think of another way around this problem?

[EDIT] Added some of the code, let me know if you'd like more. KeyDown and KeyUp I think are where I need to handle this problem

```
private void kHook_KeyDown(object sender, WindowsHookLib.KeyboardEventArgs e) {

        if (selecting)
            return; // Already selecting

        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.V && e.Modifiers == Keys.Control) {
            selecting = true;

            wHandle = WinApi.GetForegroundWindow();
            // -----------------
            // Need to display my form here without losing text edit mode in whatever application they are in and editing text in.
            WinApi.ShowInactiveTopmost(showClipboard);
            //showClipboard.Show();
            // ------------------
        }
    }


private void kHook_KeyUp(object sender, WindowsHookLib.KeyboardEventArgs e) {

        // Check if this key is one that we care about
        if (!KeyIsInteresting(e) || pasting)
            return;

        if (selecting) {
            switch (e.KeyCode) {
                case Keys.V:
                    showClipboard.Hide();
                    WinApi.SetForegroundWindow(wHandle);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10); // Wait for original window to gain regain focus
                    pasting = true;
                    SendKeys.Send("^v");
                    Clipboard.MoveToBottom(); // Add this item to the bottom so that it is first on the list next time
                    pasting = false;
                    selecting = false;
                    break;
                case Keys.Delete:
                    Clipboard.RemoveItem();
                    showClipboard.RefreshClipboardList();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: post code. If you are using global keyboard hooks you shouldn't have to focus your app.

Comment: Oh cr*p.  Consider how the [UAC Prompt works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  A screenshot of the current desktop, displayed in another.

Comment: Added code. Hans I'm not sure I understand, are you suggesting I take a screenshot, move that to another desktop, display my form in there and then what trash it all on paste? I'd still have the focus problem no?

Comment: The [`WS_EX_NOACTIVATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx) extended window style prevents a top level window from becoming the foreground window. This is the same as never gaining input focus.